# Creating a blob with node

Tags: node.js, axios, blob, readfile

I am trying to create a blob from an excel file with in node v16, the blob appears to the right size but is it missing lots of info.

```
import { Blob } from 'node:buffer';

app.get('/getBlob', async (req: any, res: any) => {
            const data = await fs.readFileSync('./files/test.xlsx');
        
            let blob = new Blob([data]);
            console.log(blob); **//Blob { size: 1224718, type: '' }**
            res.send(blob);
        });
```

When I return it via axios the size is only 2 bytes

When I return from axios using

```
   axios
          .get("http://localhost:8000/getBlob", {
            method: "GET",
            responseType: "blob",
          }
```

Logging out the response.data

```
   size: 2
    type: "application/json"
    [[Prototype]]: Blob
```

Been through all the variations of creating a blob in stackoverflow and can't seem to create the blob correctly from the buffer.

Edit: tried Base64 in the options

```
   const data = await fs.readFileSync('./files/test.xlsx', { encoding:'base64' });
```

and setting the type

```
 let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' })
```

blob now consoles out in node

```
blob Blob {
  size: 2298824,
  type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
}
```

but the same in axios it returns it as

**Blob {size: 2, type: 'application/json'}**

Comment: You have to set the blob type: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/buffer.html#new-bufferblobsources-options Axios response type are `'arraybuffer', 'document', 'json', 'text', 'stream'`: https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config Read the docs and understand what is written there.

Comment: export type ResponseType =
    | 'arraybuffer'
    | 'blob'
    | 'document'
    | 'json'
    | 'text'
    | 'stream';

Comment: I am retuning it to a browser

Comment: Thats not how it works... Node.js context != browser context. What do you see when you open the url in the browser? Post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)